# fabricjs image placing alignment issue

Tags: javascript, angular, fabricjs

i was using fabricjs for image upload and bootstrap for css after upload the image preview is coming in the top.

When i click the image hsa to come in the right side but it's coming in the bottom.

Here is my html

```
        <div class="container-fluid" style="border:1px solid red">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img *ngFor="let item of urls" (click)="onClik(item)"  [src]="item.url" class="rounded mb-3" width="180">
          <input type="file" multiple (change)="detectFiles($event)">
          <br/>
          <h1>Preview</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div id="mainarea">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-h3hdyr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) link

Example how my image is showing now

[image]

Comment: Have you already fixed it ?   looking into your stackblitz  showing  multiple images side by side

Comment: @khajaamin no still struggling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you are not attaching the newly created canvases to your container element (in fact, you just declare `container` but you don't use it at all), but to the body element. So, instead of

```
this.renderer.appendChild(document.body, newCanvas);
```

you should do

```
this.rendered.appendChild(this.container, newCanvas);
```

Also, it's likely that you will have to add `display: flex` to the container div, in order for the canvases to appear side by side.

Comment: it worked really awesome but i have one small issue it is not coming down keep on growing in x direction 

i have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Hello Please check this have changed only HTML

https://angular-ivy-mt5mbv.stackblitz.io

Comment: thanks for the help but the below user code was expectation i am almost done here

i have one more issue for example if i uploaded 2 images the image got uploaded and if again uploaded images the previous image is removed from thumbnail perspective can you help on this

Comment: If you want to preserve the previous thumbnails, just comment or remove the `this.urls = [];` line from the `detectFiles()` function.